# Creating a panda dataframe based on what I have done with PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

I want **to do the equivalent of the following in pandas without using spark.**

This is what I do in spark to generate some random data using class UsedFunctions (not the main point).

```
class UsedFunctions:
  def randomString(self,length):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str
  def clustered(self,x,numRows):
    return math.floor(x -1)/numRows
  def scattered(self,x,numRows):
    return abs((x -1 % numRows))* 1.0
  def randomised(self,seed,numRows):
    random.seed(seed)
    return abs(random.randint(0, numRows) % numRows) * 1.0
  def padString(self,x,chars,length):
    n = int(math.log10(x) + 1)
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length-n)) + str(x)
    return result_str
  def padSingleChar(self,chars,length):
    result_str = ''.join(chars for i in range(length))
    return result_str
  def println(self,lst):
    for ll in lst:
      print(ll[0])


usedFunctions = UsedFunctions()

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

numRows = 10
start = 1
end = start + 9
print ("starting at ID = ",start, ",ending on = ",end)
Range = range(start, end)
rdd = sc.parallelize(Range). \
         map(lambda x: (x, usedFunctions.clustered(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.scattered(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.randomised(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.randomString(50), \
                           usedFunctions.padString(x," ",50), \
                           usedFunctions.padSingleChar("x",4000)))
df = rdd.toDF()
```

OK how can I create a panda DataFrame df without using Spark?
I know the following spark dataframe to pandas conversion will work but using Spark is not an option here.

```
p_dfm = df.toPandas()  # converting spark DF to Pandas DF
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to retain most of your code and syntax from spark.

```
# your class and functions on top as is ...

usedFunctions = UsedFunctions()

numRows = 10
start = 1
end = start + 9
print ("starting at ID = ",start, ",ending on = ",end)
Range = range(start, end)

df =pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: (x, usedFunctions.clustered(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.scattered(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.randomised(x,numRows), \
                           usedFunctions.randomString(50), \
                           usedFunctions.padString(x," ",50), \
                           usedFunctions.padSingleChar("x",4000)), Range))
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   1   0.0 0.0 2.0 KZWeqhFWCEPyYngFbyBM... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
1   2   0.1 1.0 0.0 ffxkVZQtqMnMcLRkBOzZ... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
2   3   0.2 2.0 3.0 LIixMEOLeMaEqJomTEIJ... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
3   4   0.3 3.0 3.0 tgUzEjfebzJsZWdoHIxr... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
4   5   0.4 4.0 9.0 qVwYSVPHbDXpPdkhxEpy... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
5   6   0.5 5.0 9.0 fFWqcajQLEWVxuXbrFZm... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
6   7   0.6 6.0 5.0 jzPdeIgxLdGncfBAepfJ... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
7   8   0.7 7.0 3.0 xyimTcfipZGnzPbDFDyF... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
8   9   0.8 8.0 7.0 NxrilRavGDMfvJNScUyk... ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It is a solution.

Comment: Mich - you can click the check mark to accept the answer.